# Protecting Against DDoS attacks: Is Mod_Security and the OWASP rule set adequate?

Tags: apache, firewall, owasp, ddos, mod-security

Is `mod_sec` and the OWASP rule set adequate to protect against DDoS and DoS attacks or would you recommend taking additional steps, e.g. blocking suspicious IP addresses which have been identified by `mod_sec` using `iptables`?

Would you recommend activating `mod_evasive` in addition to `mod_sec`?

What about `ShoreWall` and [CSFirewall](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html)?

Thank you!

Comment: check out this link if it helps you: https://fossies.org/linux/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_sec only provides "rate-limiting", that can offer a degree of DOS protection, when the attack originates from same set of IP addresses. It can deny/drop connections, when let's say there are more than, say 20 requests from the same IP. It would not offer protection from DDoS, where compromised command and control hosts continue slow paced attacks spanning over days.

On your second question: I do not have much insight into mod_evasive.